# Changing a stored property in a class using protocol extensions

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am in the process of learning protocol oriented programming, I have a model of an enemy and player where the player can damage the enemy like so:

```
protocol Targetable {
    func takeDamage(damage: Int)
}

protocol Shootable {
    func shoot(target: Targetable)
}

class Pistol: Shootable {
     func shoot(target: Targetable) {
         target.takeDamage(damage: 5)
     }
}

class Enemy: Targetable {

    var health = 100

    func takeDamage(damage: Int) {
        health = health - damage
        print("Current health is: \(health)")
    }
}

class Player {

    var gun: Shootable

    func shoot(target: Targetable) {
        gun.shoot(target: target)
    }

    init(gun: Shootable) {
        self.gun = gun
    }
}

let player = Player(gun: Pistol())
let enemy = Enemy()

player.shoot(target: enemy)
```

Now, I want to create a protocol extension on `Targetable` when whichever class conforms to `Targetable` will have a default implementation of `takeDamage` which reduces the `health` property. The problem is since `health` property is a stored value I can't access `health` in the protocol extension.

I have tried doing this:

```
extension Targetable {
    func takeDamage(damage: Int, health: Int) {

    }
}
```

But at the call site, it doesn't seem to make sense to pass `health` into the function that way.

How should I go about implementing this? thanks!

Comment: Why not add `health` property in `Targetable`?

Comment: You are absolutely spot on, thanks!